# How can I show a pop-up after completing a task in the background?

Tags: android

I want to show a pop-up message after completing my current task, which is running in the background. The pop-up message must be poped up on current activity.

How i can achieve this?

Comment: The title should reflect what the problem is about. "Hi,Android developers" doesn't do that. Please remember that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: Before I help you I need some more details from you. What do you use in background. Is it asynctask or service?

Comment: Use Async Task......Simple question and simple answer....

Comment: @joa yes i will remember that,as i am new on this forum and in development also...dats y...

Comment: @prasham yes in background progress bar is running which have some time limit(Ex. 2min) then after completing 2min i want to show pop-up message. i have done with progress bar now pop-up message is remain....so,please tell me how to achieve???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) or [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

Toast is less intrusive, and cannot take any input, usually best to alert the user of a timer going off or something similar, they disappear by themselves.

AlertDialog is a bit more intrusive since they (usually) don't go away by them selfs, but they can take input, but from my experience they are best for picking an option like "are you sure you want to exit?" or displaying a loading bar since you can put images and other widgets in them.

But another way would be a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Although this doesn't "pop-out" it is another possibility and depending on your app could be a better choice.

Comment: as you said think its better to use notification if running a service or alert dialog if its an activity.

Answer (score 1):

[AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Toast.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: toast is disapear automatically but i must see that message box until i perform some function on that message box only..so,please help me how i can achieve this???

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
You can use handle

The way is :

**in your background class**

```
protected Handler m_Handle = null;
```

than you finish your task add 

`m_Handle.sendEmptyMessage(for ex: PopupType );`

in your activity

```
public Handler myHandle = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
      show dialog
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do the talk in background using the services then show popup up activity same way that i have did [android:chat app popup view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854395/androidchat-app-popup-view)

Thank you.