# How to display alert diaolog(popup) from backgroung running service?

Tags: android, service

I am having a background `Service` which is not binded to any of the application(or Activity). It's monitoring incoming messages, and on receiving message, I have to show one dialog popup. I have tried defining one method which is for showing alert dialog, but it gives exception as `"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"`
I really don't have any idea regarding how to solve this problem. I have searched many post like this over here but not getting how to resolve this one. Help highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804684/2149195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Handler seperately like this.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
 @Override
 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

//Call you method in This one...
 displayDialog(); or whatever method name is
 }
};
```

Now where you are calling the displayDialog() method or what ever named dialog. replace the following code.

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

2nd Posible Solution is :

put your method calling code inside the following:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

public void run(){

//Call the method here
}

});
```

Hope this helps

Thanks
sHaH

Comment: Still i m getting exception as "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()". I am not getting concept of Looper, can you help me?

Comment: on my side runOnUIThread() works perfectly fine... you should try that

Answer (score 0):

Might be repeated question

If you want to open a dialog from background service then you can not do but there is a way you can open your activity as dialog from service for more info and code

follow below link

[android:chat app popup view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854395/androidchat-app-popup-view/6854761#6854761)