# Open a PopUpWindow from an AppWidget

Tags: android

As it doesn't appear to be possible to put an EditText in an AppWidget, I would like to open a PopUpWindow with an EditText when I click on it.

I know how to open an Activity from an AppWidget and I also know how open a PopUpWindow from an Activity. I don't, however, know how to open a PopUpWindow from an AppWidget. I've looked into many classes in the javadoc (Intent, RemoteViews, PendingIntent, etc.), but I can't find how to start this PopUpWindow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You know that `AppWidgetProvider` is a `BroadcastReceiver`.[Android Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) says:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this
>   function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer
>   active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at
>   that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the
>   system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation
>   completes.
>
> **In particular, you may not show a dialog** or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the former, you should instead use the
>   **NotificationManager** API. For the latter, you can use
>   *`Context.startService()`* to send a command to the **service**.

It seems you have three ways:

1. Use a service to show popup(see [How to display alert diaolog(popup) from backgroung running service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924900/how-to-display-alert-diaologpopup-from-backgroung-running-service))
2. Use notification manager(see [AlarmManager never calling onRecieve in AlarmReceiver/BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733736/alarmmanager-never-calling-onrecieve-in-alarmreceiver-broadcastreceiver)).
3. Create an activity whit dialog theme(so it looks like a popup) and display it when user click your AppWidget.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the appWidget open an activity which then shows a dialog fragment, or make the activity look like a dialog using a dialog style.