# pop up alert dialog box from service in android

Tags: android, service, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to build activity aware app. 
I used the activity recognition example from  android developers as starting point.
In this example the moment the user starts moving notification appears with request to turn on the GPS.
I'm trying to replace this notification with an alarm dialog box and some sound.
the simple and most common alert box that I found is not working for me since it is imposible to create an allert from service. 
Thanks to Harsh for giving me an idea of  activity.
I will post the code the moment it will work.
Thank you in advance 
as promised the working code of an alert box invoked from service :
1) the code in the service file:

```
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(this, MyAlert.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

2) the code in the alert activity .java file :

```
    public class MyAlert extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_alert);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // set title
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Your Message")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    stopService(getIntent());
                    dialog.cancel();
                    finish();
                }
            });

    // create alert dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

3)alert activity manifest was left empty of code, just a layout
4)the manifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.igor.map.MyAlert"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    </activity>
```

All works, one thing still has a problem, when i press the Ok button the allert closes but the label of the app stays until I click on screen.

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Possible Duplicate => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924900/how-to-display-alert-diaologpopup-from-backgroung-running-service

Comment: you cant use builder in service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start an Activity from service, and declare activity as dialog in your manifest. Like this

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.DialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

Comment: would you be so kind to explain a bit more?

Comment: Thank you very much. One last thing. Do I need to build the alert from scratch or will it work creating only the java file??

Comment: You just need to put some controls in it as you want it to be designed. And you have to write some logic based on your requirement.

Comment: Harsh Hello, I've posted my alertBox code, there is a small issue I cant find an explanation for. would you be so kind to check it out?

Comment: Call finish(); after the line dialog.cancel();