# Showing a POPUP Window in background in Android

Tags: android, popup, whatsapp

I am creating an app in which I have to show list of messages like this one
[image: whatsapp popup]

The problem is that when I receive a broadcast receiver I am not able to show a Popup Window while,if I start an Dialog activity than due to the context of receiver,the old activity is shown behind the dialog activity.

Any example of such type will be a pleasure...

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498605/how-to-create-a-popup-window-in-android

OR

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027149/popup-dialog-android-from-background-thread

OR

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714813/show-pop-up-from-background-service-in-android

OR

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139143/how-can-i-show-a-pop-up-after-completing-a-task-in-the-background

Comment: @TheDarkKnight - I have checked all the above links before posting..None of them solves my problem